# Anular exibição de erros no console

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma forma de bloquer a exibiçao de erros no console? tipo erros Javascript ou algo do tipo?

Comment: corrigindo os erros.

Comment: Qual seria o propósito de "esconder" os erros? Simplesmente impedir que um usuário visualize eles ao carregar a página ou é porquê ele está quebrando em algum ponto do código que não faz diferença/não se quer arrumar no momento?

Comment: @nmindz os dois.. tipo estou usando js para websockets e quando nao conecta ele mostra o endereço do servidor.. é capricho msm

Comment: Se você realmente precisa disto é melhor dar um override na funão de exibição e retornar em branco

Answer (score 7):

Use o bloco **Try** **catch** 
segue um exemplo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
try {
    //veja que escrevi  documentOO e o correto é document
    documentOO.write('Olá Mundo');
}
catch(err) {
    document.write("Ocorreu um erro: " + err.message);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode redefinir o console e seu método `log`:

```
window.console = {
    log: function(){}
};
console.log('sumiu!');
```

Mas isso só afeta suas chamadas diretas a `console.log`. Se a ideia é omitir a exibição de erros lançados pelo código, só se você tratar o erro como sugeriu o @ClevertonCarneiro. Mas cuidado com isso, na maioria das vezes é o caso de corrigir o erro em vez de tentar omiti-lo.

Comment: onde tem essa funçao completa? onde ela executa o log corretamente

Comment: Como assim, não entendi sua dúvida. O `console` é um objeto disponibilizado pelo browser.